# Build a list of filenames in Dropzone.js to pass in form submit

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, arrays

I have been working to build a list of file names that are queued for upload in the Dropzone.js. I have been searching the forums for weeks looking for an answer. https://github.com/enyo/dropzone/issues/1652

I started here:
https://github.com/enyo/dropzone/wiki/Upload-all-files-with-a-button.

In this section of the code is where I am working:

```
    this.on("addedfile", function() {
      console.log(this.getAcceptedFiles(file));
    });
```

This function returns an array of information about the queued files to be uploaded on click. The array looks like this:

```
[File(75099)]
   0: File(75099)
     accepted: true
     lastModified: 1508061061300
     lastModifiedDate: Sun Oct 15 2017 05:51:01 GMT-0400 (Eastern Daylight  Time) {}
     name: "ITI-TV-REPAIR-FORM.pdf"
     previewElement: div.dz-preview.dz-file-preview
     previewTemplate: div.dz-preview.dz-file-preview
     size: 75099
     status: "queued"
     type: "application/pdf"
     upload: {progress: 0, total: 75099, bytesSent: 0}
     webkitRelativePath: ""
     _removeLink: a.dz-remove
     __proto__: File
     length: 1
     __proto__: Array(0)
```

I know that if I use this.getAcceptedFiles().length. It will return 1. As it should since length is in the "root" of the array. But trying to access the name is where I am stumped. The hard part is that the [File(75099)] at the head of the array will always change but the key name will always be in the same place.

I'm thinking out loud while I type this up. The thing I just thought of is if I can do a key value search of the array since I know the key that I am looking for is name:.

I have tried accessing the name value with

```
this.getAcceptedFiles().name
```

Of course, that did not work. So my ending question would be what is the best way to access the key value in this array to get the name of the file?

UPDATE: Figure it out!!!

```
            this.on("addedfile", function(file) {
                //returns file names that are in the queue
                console.log(file.name);

            });
```

Full code here: https://github.com/enyo/dropzone/issues/1652

Comment: Did you try `this.getAcceptedFiles()[0].name` ?

Comment: Yes and it returns name undefined

Comment: check this too `this.getAcceptedFiles()[0][0].name`

Comment: Tried it and: expenses.php?id=144:57 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of undefined
    at Dropzone.<anonymous> (expenses.php?id=144:57)
    at Dropzone.Emitter.emit (VM17716 dropzone.js:58)
    at Dropzone.addFile (VM17716 dropzone.js:986)
    at Dropzone._addFilesFromItems (VM17716 dropzone.js:912)
    at Dropzone.drop (VM17716 dropzone.js:876)
    at HTMLFormElement.listeners.events.drop (VM17716 dropzone.js:655)

Comment: I updated my answer, let me know if I miss something

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `addedfile` event is called whenever a file is added to the list of uploaded files, also you can get the added file as parameter in the event callback:

```
this.on("addedfile", function(file) {
    console.log(file.name)
});
```

Here is a working example:

```js
Dropzone.options.myDropzone = {

  // Prevents Dropzone from uploading dropped files immediately
  autoProcessQueue: false,
  
  acceptedFiles: 'image/*',

  init: function() {
    var submitButton = document.querySelector("#submit-all");
    myDropzone = this;

    submitButton.addEventListener("click", function() {
      myDropzone.processQueue(); // Tell Dropzone to process all queued files.
    });

    // You might want to show the submit button only when 
    // files are dropped here:
    this.on("addedfile", function(file) {
      console.log(file.name)
    });

  }
};
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>

<script src="https://rawgit.com/enyo/dropzone/master/dist/dropzone.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://rawgit.com/enyo/dropzone/master/dist/dropzone.css">

<!-- Change /upload-target to your upload address -->
<form action="/upload-target" class="dropzone" id="my-dropzone"></form>
<br>
<button id="submit-all">Submit all files</button>
```

Hope this helps